# PhoneGap 2.1.0 not working on iOS 4.3.3

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I've developed an hello world example using PhoneGap Build and it's working fine on iOS 5 but it's crashing on iOS 4.33.

Here's the crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 96D8E936-F4A3-43C6-864E-5BE8631E454E
CrashReporter Key:   c2c95d63cf11603079ae85170ab939102266467f
Hardware Model:      iPhone2,1
Process:         HelloWorld210 [305]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/8DFA1B8E-DF57-41F6-A504-261D2185358C/HelloWorld210.app/HelloWorld210
Identifier:      HelloWorld210
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-10-11 15:09:53.724 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J2)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x00000001, 0xe7ffdefe
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/8DFA1B8E-DF57-41F6-A504-261D2185358C/HelloWorld210.app/HelloWorld210
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
  Dyld Version: 191.3

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x2fe01080 0x2fe00000 + 4224
1   dyld                            0x2fe02a40 0x2fe00000 + 10816
2   dyld                            0x2fe02b00 0x2fe00000 + 11008
3   libdyld.dylib                   0x3185844e 0x31857000 + 5198
4   libdyld.dylib                   0x31858374 0x31857000 + 4980
5   HelloWorld210                   0x00038474 0x1000 + 226420
6   HelloWorld210                   0x00003b8c 0x1000 + 11148
7   UIKit                           0x3362fa0c 0x335f9000 + 223756
8   HelloWorld210                   0x000384ca 0x1000 + 226506
9   HelloWorld210                   0x0000382a 0x1000 + 10282
10  UIKit                           0x3362e81a 0x335f9000 + 219162
11  UIKit                           0x33628b5e 0x335f9000 + 195422
12  UIKit                           0x335fd7d0 0x335f9000 + 18384
13  UIKit                           0x335fd20e 0x335f9000 + 16910
14  UIKit                           0x335fcc4c 0x335f9000 + 15436
15  GraphicsServices                0x34643e70 0x3463f000 + 20080
16  CoreFoundation                  0x33b47a90 0x33ad2000 + 481936
17  CoreFoundation                  0x33b49838 0x33ad2000 + 489528
18  CoreFoundation                  0x33b4a606 0x33ad2000 + 493062
19  CoreFoundation                  0x33adaebc 0x33ad2000 + 36540
20  CoreFoundation                  0x33adadc4 0x33ad2000 + 36292
21  UIKit                           0x33627d42 0x335f9000 + 191810
22  UIKit                           0x33625800 0x335f9000 + 182272
23  HelloWorld210                   0x00003650 0x1000 + 9808
24  HelloWorld210                   0x00003600 0x1000 + 9728

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x344b83ec 0x344a6000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ea66d8 0x33e72000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ea6bbc 0x33e72000 + 215996

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x344b8fbc 0x344a6000 + 77756
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x31415032 0x3140f000 + 24626
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3141603a 0x3140f000 + 28730
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x314155ea 0x3140f000 + 26090
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ea658a 0x33e72000 + 214410
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ea6bbc 0x33e72000 + 215996

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x344b5c00 0x344a6000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x344b5758 0x344a6000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33b482b8 0x33ad2000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33b4a562 0x33ad2000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33adaebc 0x33ad2000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33adadc4 0x33ad2000 + 36292
6   WebCore                         0x3235b27e 0x32355000 + 25214
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ea530a 0x33e72000 + 209674
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ea6bb4 0x33e72000 + 215988

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x344b5c00 0x344a6000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x344b5758 0x344a6000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33b482b8 0x33ad2000 + 484024
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33b4a562 0x33ad2000 + 492898
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33adaebc 0x33ad2000 + 36540
5   CoreFoundation                  0x33adadc4 0x33ad2000 + 36292
6   Foundation                      0x34a567f6 0x34a2c000 + 174070
7   Foundation                      0x34a49382 0x34a2c000 + 119682
8   Foundation                      0x34abb5c6 0x34a2c000 + 587206
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ea530a 0x33e72000 + 209674
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33ea6bb4 0x33e72000 + 215988

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x2fe4e994    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000330      r3: 0x2fe26624
    r4: 0x2fe4e994    r5: 0x0017b6ac      r6: 0x2fe19259      r7: 0x2fdfe234
    r8: 0x2fe29550    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x2fdfe218     r11: 0x0005ee5f
    ip: 0x6c79642e    sp: 0x2fdfe234      lr: 0x2fe02a47      pc: 0x2fe01080
  cpsr: 0x60000010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x4efff +HelloWorld210 armv7  <35adc327c6093465852999b16b55a64b> /var/mobile/Applications/8DFA1B8E-DF57-41F6-A504-261D2185358C/HelloWorld210.app/HelloWorld210
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe25fff  dyld armv7  <bb9bfc7d242331d29a79adf7ef7aaa18> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3122f000 - 0x31266fff  Security armv7  <6599f42a910b3b31a0e1d98c883d61cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x312b6000 - 0x312bffff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x312c0000 - 0x312c6fff  IAP armv7  <c0f4c99a1b493e489948f231ad9238e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x312f0000 - 0x312f9fff  ITSync armv7  <ba8b48d061903e4096774344448776d0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x312fa000 - 0x31306fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x31307000 - 0x3130cfff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x31353000 - 0x31354fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3140f000 - 0x3141cfff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9a0511ad5ebc3db898f1f49ed1a73d34> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x314e3000 - 0x314fcfff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x31553000 - 0x3155efff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x3166a000 - 0x316b8fff  CoreMotion armv7  <58c353bb7e33361f881da07c72f4cdfb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x316b9000 - 0x316bffff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <f9277ee9b85b3722975ad319a323aca0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x316e8000 - 0x316e8fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x316e9000 - 0x31748fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <0b36b2272aa33a8c9aa22d99c89d7189> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x31749000 - 0x31749fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x31857000 - 0x31858fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x31859000 - 0x3188efff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x318e1000 - 0x31919fff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3191d000 - 0x3191ffff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x31940000 - 0x31942fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x31a87000 - 0x31b8bfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <61a94142e2d23dafa2964190dd46e9e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x31b8c000 - 0x31bb0fff  MediaControl armv7  <1cfc7d79f554357ab59eb69f9efebf07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControl.framework/MediaControl
0x31bb1000 - 0x31bb7fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x31bb8000 - 0x31bbdfff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <c7cfe523e2d73521abc01587313ef730> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x31bbe000 - 0x31bbefff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x31c0c000 - 0x31cb5fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x31fd2000 - 0x31fe8fff  EAP8021X armv7  <9fefc0ada30435fbb3b51818c74f6cb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x31ff5000 - 0x31ff8fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x31ff9000 - 0x3207dfff  AVFoundation armv7  <eeaf5f4f822436a5bd1655f536e69879> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x3208e000 - 0x32092fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d2f7fd2a352b3cd59c564be34b53cf80> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x32093000 - 0x3209afff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x320c9000 - 0x320ccfff  ArtworkCache armv7  <4863e321afee3ac5a3749e50cd926597> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x32149000 - 0x32172fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x32176000 - 0x321a5fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x321a6000 - 0x321d9fff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x32355000 - 0x32960fff  WebCore armv7  <07941e59d0a33f94802c16c76238fddf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x329b8000 - 0x32b0cfff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x32b0f000 - 0x32c30fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <65f6c8701b563542820a26b0dfc4f6a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x32c34000 - 0x32c34fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <42d8aa2a31843a6e8bfff745644a7ba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x32d14000 - 0x32d20fff  HomeSharing armv7  <2df6957cdfea31aea12eebf27ca1691c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x32d21000 - 0x32d28fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x32dc3000 - 0x32f0ffff  MediaToolbox armv7  <482b13059e8a329fa5d832baede25103> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x32f26000 - 0x32f28fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <9e7efa009730322f84bbc5d8bf1ded94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x32f29000 - 0x32f33fff  AccountSettings armv7  <d083fb384dc7311eb6766b9b2d2dd9c8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x33546000 - 0x33548fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x33549000 - 0x335e6fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <e354aeb3d96e30338e90cc3638ffe81b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x335e7000 - 0x335ebfff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a0772a32cd8b3b9194bb0c29807c1c5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x335f9000 - 0x33986fff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x33989000 - 0x339cffff  CoreTelephony armv7  <af7d1e770e5a3ffd8834a57fb5d40557> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x33a20000 - 0x33a27fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x33a73000 - 0x33aa7fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <570c63dc3a273a5a8c9072fd5567f5c1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x33ad2000 - 0x33bb7fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a8444f997111304c9571b3ff974b769c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x33bb8000 - 0x33c02fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x33d60000 - 0x33d9ffff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <33dcf9a403ae3fd5971d6030ada2fcab> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x33e13000 - 0x33e55fff  CoreAudio armv7  <c972fd5f8e89333ca680b9a33587f896> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x33e72000 - 0x33ef3fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <a7077267b6743ed3bbdd86d4380c75d9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x33f15000 - 0x33f1afff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x33f55000 - 0x33f65fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <66d9047da79a31daa887e6d84c42ecb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x33faf000 - 0x34073fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <6b51e76fde9f381bb7b3bc5badbfee3a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34084000 - 0x340f3fff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x340f4000 - 0x34107fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <529ea6e3a87230ce9f6cf3285c22429c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x34110000 - 0x34113fff  ApplePushService armv7  <015c68c15621348db9f6a012499170e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x34157000 - 0x34244fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3428e000 - 0x342cefff  CoreMedia armv7  <8e0570582ba535bfa74f1f00eef64376> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x342cf000 - 0x34320fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x34344000 - 0x3438afff  CoreLocation armv7  <c1924042951e3df98515c7bf36093c1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x344a6000 - 0x344bdfff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <a06ec84e53bf32098b63c0caebdb45b6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x344c2000 - 0x34568fff  Celestial armv7  <7fbd02fa664b33babaf0327c320d1491> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x34569000 - 0x3456cfff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x345ca000 - 0x34607fff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x34636000 - 0x3463efff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <63f11756c4aa3262b2317ff3b8e2a977> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x3463f000 - 0x3464bfff  GraphicsServices armv7  <ff78a9636e933f0dbd222f8d26209788> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3464f000 - 0x34692fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f790c26852cb3cf298abe56bc9a3940b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x34696000 - 0x346b3fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3478d000 - 0x34791fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x34792000 - 0x3479bfff  MobileWiFi armv7  <03d98d5cf6383695aa7d8a88da52f410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x34810000 - 0x3481efff  OpenGLES armv7  <5a76beaeaa013f0cbf16e5cb154598ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x34938000 - 0x34970fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x34a2c000 - 0x34b4bfff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x34b4c000 - 0x34b4efff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x34b67000 - 0x34b7cfff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x34b7d000 - 0x34b82fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x365d6000 - 0x365f6fff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x366ed000 - 0x3679cfff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x36849000 - 0x36908fff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x36bca000 - 0x36bcbfff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x36bef000 - 0x36bf4fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <e57c2b9054b831d9a37119baaa4947cb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x36de3000 - 0x36de4fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <e8858a499d663e6a9e3c188521273cc1> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x36de5000 - 0x36df2fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x36e1e000 - 0x36ee4fff  MusicLibrary armv7  <71a09022bd8b3b6a90a250199d190f10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x36f36000 - 0x36f48fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <659ea9d5b13d3fefb37acff09016a69c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x36f85000 - 0x36fb8fff  StoreServices armv7  <d526715648f435c3aac4c42953e76d20> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x3703b000 - 0x3703cfff  DataMigration armv7  <42e9e87a4e0735c3837e27d4f2adcf55> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x370d5000 - 0x3712afff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x3712b000 - 0x37418fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <b855d60dac01310495453bddfd004f0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x37422000 - 0x3745efff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9d97699e44ee3651ba4ac37e5adec35b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x3750d000 - 0x375befff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x375bf000 - 0x375c2fff  MediaRemote armv7  <0804293b2774359189f3a67e2c81558d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x37628000 - 0x37629fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3762a000 - 0x3773cfff  MediaPlayer armv7  <da848c0745a637af81d7edd962a09324> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x37740000 - 0x37743fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <43311c113a9d3182b7d007129819f029> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x37744000 - 0x3785efff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3785f000 - 0x3785ffff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x37895000 - 0x3792afff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x37959000 - 0x379a7fff  GMM armv7  <049361f664eb3f30b0d25cd56ffc1f0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x379a8000 - 0x379c7fff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
```

Comment: Why do you even want to support iOS 3. It's be depricated and a lot of thing will not work on it. Especially if you are also targeting iOS 6 and the iPhone 5 then you deployment target can be lower then 4.3

Comment: @rckoenes the reason why I'm upgrading to PhoneGap 2.1.0 is to support iOS 6.

Comment: The you will be forced to stop support the ARMV6 and iOS 3

Comment: @rckoenes could you please provide a link to an official documentation confirming the  lack of support of PhoneGap 2.1.0 to iOS 3?

Comment: The problem is that iOS6 does requires a AMRV7 or newer processor. And Xcode 4.5 can't compile for ARMV6 any more, since any iOS lower then 4.3 should be able to support an ARMv6. So if you tager get iOS6 you will need to drop support for the ARMv6. This is not just for Phonegap but for all method of building apps that will support iOS 6

Comment: @rckoenes I thought that was testing on a iOS 3 but actually is iOS 4.3.3, it should have worked right?

Comment: Yes, 4.3.3 should work, then we will need some kind of crash log to help you.

Comment: @rckoenes the OS version of the mobile device (iPhone 3G) has been updated and isn't the one that was originally installed, so I think the problem is that PhoneGap 2.1.0 doesn't support the CPU of the mobile device, right?

Comment: Yes, the iPhone 3G has an ARMv6 CPU which is not supported by the iOS 6 SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With iOS 6 apple update Xcode to 4.5 en removed support for the ARMv6 (iPhone, iPhone 3G, iPod Touch 1g/2g,....).

Thus you can't target iOS 3 or and thing lower then 4.3 (which is not support by ARMv6 Devices).

Comment: I've updated to PhoneGap 2.2.0 and now the application works on iPhone 3G. How is it possible?