# Supported iOS version on PhoneGap 2.2.0

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova

I'm developing a web application using PhoneGap and I'm not understanding how does PhoneGap 2.1.0 doesn't support iOS3 and PhoneGap 2.2.0 supports it.

The reason why I'm asking this it's because supposedly the [minimum supported version of XCode 4.5 is  iOS 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838104/phonegap-2-1-0-not-working-on-ios-4-3-3).

Answer (score 0):

But the Phonegap requirements to iOS are equals like below description

[Requirements to Phonegap 2.1.0:](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS)

Xcode 4.3+
Xcode Command Line Tools
Intel-based computer with Mac OS X Lion or greater (10.7+)
Necessary for installing on device:
Apple iOS device (iPhone, iPad, iPod Touch)
iOS developer certificate

[Requirements to Phonegap 2.2.0:](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS)

Xcode 4.5+
Xcode Command Line Tools
Intel-based computer with Mac OS X Lion or greater (10.7+)
Necessary for installing on device:
Apple iOS device (iPhone, iPad, iPod Touch)
iOS developer certificate

Comment: That's right. If it happens, you should report to Phonegap support team: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/products/nitobi_phonegap_build